# AngularJS: how to pass an element to directive and show as source code?

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

Is it possible to see this `<p id="space-for-buttons" my-directive>{{something}}</p>` as source code in html document, if clicked?

This is my directive so far:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind("click", function () {
            angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons'))
                .append($compile("<br><code>" + scope + "</code>")(scope));
        });
    }
}});
```

But it shows only `[object Object]`. I want just show an example of this `{{expression | filter : maybesomemore}}` if clicked.

Comment: Scope IS an object.  Why would you expect it to be anything other than an object?

Comment: this is my work in university and want to show a source code with directives and filters, etc and without switching to the IDE

Comment: You are misunderstanding what I am saying.  Scope is an object.  If you attempt to render an object, it will always be displayed as `[object Object]`.  That is how JavaScript works.  Instead, you should be trying to render a specific property of scope.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far:

```
<ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="booleanVal = toggle()"> {{-quantity | number : 4}}
            <code ng-show="booleanVal">
                <span ng-non-bindable> {{-quantity | number : 4}}</span>
            </code>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and toggle function

```
$scope.booleanVal = false;
$scope.toggle = function () {
    return !this.booleanVal;
};
```